# Exclude certain windows from being minimized with windows-D shortcut

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, productivity

In Windows 7, I would like to be able to select certain windows to exclude from being minimized when I press Windows-D.  Is this possible?  3rd party programs are okay.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** In list of [Keyboard shortcuts in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts) when you switch to **Windows 7** you can see

> <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>     Display the desktop.

It does not mention any exceptions allowing to exclude some windows.